# How to get all telegram invite links

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

Introductory: the telegram channel has a lot of invite links by which users join the channel, and this information is available in the telegram client, which means it can also be obtained via the Client API.

Task: write a script for unloading users (telegram user id) which user joined the channel using which invite link.

I tried to run that code:

```
import asyncio
import config
import csv
from telethon import TelegramClient, functions, types


async def main():
    client = TelegramClient('session_name', config.api_id, config.api_hash)

    await client.connect()

    result = await client(functions.messages.GetExportedChatInvitesRequest(peer=types.InputPeerChat(chat_id), admin_id=types.InputUser(admin_user_id, 0), limit=200))

    with open('invite_links.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as csvfile:
        writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
        writer.writerow(['user_id', 'invite_link']) 
        async for link in result.invites:
            async for user in client.iter_participants(chat_id, limit=None):
                if user.invited_by == link.creator:
                    writer.writerow([user.id, link.link])

    await client.disconnect()

asyncio.run(main())
```

But I don't understand what arguments does the `functions.messages.GetExportedChatInvitesRequest` method take and how to work with it.

And I got that traceback:

```
Request caused struct.error: required argument is not an integer: GetExportedChatInvitesRequest(peer=InputPeerChat(chat_id='783156128'), admin_id=InputUser(user_id='1644201768', access_hash=0), limit=200, revoked=None, offset_date=None, offset_link=None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\daniilpolyakov3\main.py", line 29, in <module>
    asyncio.run(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 190, in run
    return runner.run(main)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\runners.py", line 118, in run
    return self._loop.run_until_complete(task)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1008.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 653, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\Python\daniilpolyakov3\main.py", line 15, in main
    result = await client(functions.messages.GetExportedChatInvitesRequest(peer=types.InputPeerChat(chat_id), admin_id=types.InputUser(admin_user_id, 0), limit=200))
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Paganel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 30, in __call__
    return await self._call(self._sender, request, ordered=ordered)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Paganel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\telethon\client\users.py", line 63, in _call
    future = sender.send(request, ordered=ordered)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Paganel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\telethon\network\mtprotosender.py", line 181, in send
    state = RequestState(request)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Paganel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\telethon\network\requeststate.py", line 17, in __init__    self.data = bytes(request)
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Paganel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\telethon\tl\tlobject.py", line 194, in __bytes__
    return self._bytes()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Paganel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\telethon\tl\functions\messages.py", line 2357, in _bytes
    self.peer._bytes(),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Paganel\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages\telethon\tl\types\__init__.py", line 12666, in _bytes
    struct.pack('<q', self.chat_id),
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
struct.error: required argument is not an integer
```

Why I got a ConnectionError? What can I do to make my code works? Please help me.

Comment: The bottom lines of your traceback pretty much explain the problem. It seems that the `chat_id` is not an integer. Try adding a `print(chat_id)` before the line where you are invoking the method.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
result = await client(functions.messages.GetExportedChatInvitesRequest(peer=types.InputPeerChannel(chat_id,access_hash = 12345)
,admin_id=admin_user_id
,limit=200))
```

It worked for me

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello, please don't post code only and add an explantation as to why you think that this is the optimal solution. People are supposed to learn from your answer, which might not occur if they just copy paste code without knowing why it should be used.